# Date picker: Cannot scroll throug all years using ngbDatepicker

Tags: calendar, ng-bootstrap, angular9, hijri

**Expected behavior**

I want a user to be able to select all years in the year range in the date picker in hijri.

**Actual behavior**

A user can only choose 15 in the range. Say the range goes from 1436 - 1417, the user would first have to click on 1417, and then he would click the list again and could now select down to 1416. How to I modify the code so a user can scroll from all years and don't have to click multiple times to get to the right year?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to set minDate and maxDate like that:

```
 <input class="form-control" (click)="d.toggle()" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                  [maxDate]="maxDate"  [minDate]="minDate" [startDate]="startDate"
                                  placement="bottom"
                                  name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

and in typescript code :

```
  maxDate ={year: new Date().getUTCFullYear()-16,month: 12, day: 31}
  minDate ={year: new Date().getUTCFullYear()-100,month: 12, day: 31}
  startDate={year: new Date().getUTCFullYear()-20,month: new Date().getUTCMonth(), day: 1}
```

Comment: there is no requirement to set max date here, and need to show all the years

Comment: I think you haven't understand my question, i want to show all the years in dopdown but next year shows only when i click on last year

Comment: i think i did understand it,you want to see 1416 1415 1414 without clicking on 1417 and reopen the dropdown,i had the same issu and i fixed it by the way i told u, did you try it?